# Put a case value in the middle of a sentence (formula)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a little trouble with excel
i dont knonw if it possible but i wanna add a cell value in the middle of my sentence
it goes like this

this is my case E61

```
I have =(E60) cars
```

and in the case E60 i can put 1 - 2- 3- 4

is there any way to do this with a formula? i cant use macro or vba stuff
thanks for your time it realy apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need string concatenation.

```
="I have " & E60 & " cars"
```

Comment: but any luck can you tell me what i did wrong here?

 =IF(E62="OUI","  ANCRE SORTIE DE "&I62&" CM AVEC UN ANGLE DE "&H62&"")

it work very well the only thing is if E62 is empty it type me false
i want if E62 is empty to just stay empty

is it possible to do that?

Comment: @AJ You can add an empty string to the missing `value_if_false` part, like `...H62&"", "")`. If `E62` is not `OUI`, it will show a blank cell.

Comment: thanks you so much for ur time Light very apreciated it working perfectly